# How to Insert Nested XML structure in SOAP Header in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1

Tags: xml, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a following nested structure that i want to insert in the soap header and i am using **Header** mediator for that.

**XML that need to be inserted in Soap Header:**

```
    <res:PageHeader xmlns:res="http://example.com">
     <res:PageId>32332323</res:PageId>
  </res:PageHeader>
```

I want to pick "PageId" value dynamically from an property called as "SavedPageId".

**Header Mediator Code:**

```
 <header xmlns:res="http://example.com" name="res:&lt;PageHeader&gt;&lt;PageId&gt;&lt;/PageId&gt;&lt;/PageHeader" scope="default" expression="get-property('SavedPageId')"/>
```

**Result:**

```
  <soapenv:Header>
  <res:<PageHeader>
  <PageId></PageId>
  </PageHeader xmlns:res="http://example.com">232323232</res:<PageHeader>
  <PageId></PageId>
  </PageHeader>
  </soapenv:Header>
```

**Expected Result:**

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <res:PageHeader xmlns:res="http://example.com">
     <res:PageId>32332323</res:PageId>
  </res:PageHeader>
    </soapenv:Header>
```

How should i configure my Header mediator for this nested xml structure and also i want to populate value from a property. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Far as I can tell , you need to use xpath inside your header like:

```
 <header xmlns:res="http://example.com" name="res:PageHeader" scope="default" expression="//xpath/for/SavedPageId"/>
```

Else ,try using a payloadFactory to build your message :

```
<property name="soapBody"
          expression="//soapenv:Body/*"
          scope="default"
          type="STRING"/>
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
<format>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Header>
            <res:PageHeader xmlns:res="http://example.com">
                <res:PageId>$1</res:PageId>
            </res:PageHeader>
        </soapenv:Header> 
        <soapenv:Body>
            $2
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
</format>
    <args>
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('SavedPageId')"/> <!-- Can also use : expression="$ctx:SavedPageId" -->
        <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('soapBody')"/>
    </args>
</payloadFactory>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to save the dynamic value into a property.
Then use the below code:

```
<header scope="default">
                <res:PageHeader xmlns:res="http://example.com">
                    <res:PageId/>
                </res:PageHeader>
            </header>
            <enrich>
                <source type="property" property="saveValueInProperty"/>
                <target xmlns:res="http://example.com" action="child" xpath="$header/res:PageHeader/res:PageID/text()"/>
            </enrich>
```

This should probably work.

Comment: I have tried your method. I have stored the page ID value in following property "SavePageId" but when i try to use it in enrich mediator, it is giving me error that "Failed to get the source for enriching"

Comment: just log the property value and see if any value is being saved in it or not.
also please post your eclipse syntax.

Comment: i have solved the above mentioning problem. Now it is giving following error . Invalid target object to be enrich. When i remove "text()" from the end of the Xpath. Then it works but the field pageId does not get populated. It remains empty.

Comment: where is the property being added then?